# Search empty fields

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I'm trying to exclude search results that have a field that stores the ID of an item is empty. This field, for example, is called 'type'. I haven't been able to do this using LINQ. Here is my code example.

```
 public class SearchItem : SearchResultItem
 {
    [IndexField("type")]
    public string Type{ get; set; }    
 }

 public class Search
 {
    public static IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(new SitecoreIndexableItem(Sitecore.Context.Item));

        using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var indexItems = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Type))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ReleaseDate);
             
            foreach(var indexItem in indexItems)
            {
                var tempItem = indexItem.GetItem();
                items.Add(tempItem);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
 }
```

The empty string comparison isn't working and it the items collection contains items that have empty strings for Type field. I'm using out of the box settings for Lucene.

Also, please poke holes in my code if you see something not right. This is my first time with Sitecore 7 Search.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this but I don't think it's possible to do negative matches in Lucene like you would with SQL for example. By using IsNullOrEmpty, you're saying you need to identify nulls/empty values in the index, but these would never have been added to the index in the first place so there's nothing to match. Bottom line, I don't think you can check for absence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the string.IsnullOrEmpty is supported by Sitecore Linq, try var indexItems = context.GetQueryable()
                .Where(x => x.Type != null)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ReleaseDate);

Comment: could you please comment if i'm incorrect, simply downgrading the answer does no good to people that read this.

Comment: Not sure who downgraded it but your answer is correct. That's how I ended up using my code.I upvoted it to remove the negative :)

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore and Lucene do not support empty strings since an empty field is not in the index. There is no document in the index for an empty item. This post might help you in using Range queries.

[Sitecore + Lucene Search FieldQuery with and empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869427/sitecore-lucene-search-fieldquery-with-and-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

Please check with any index viewer tool like Luke and confirm that the index filed type is created or not and if getting created then it is storing the expected value or not. 
Try checking by calling function so that you can debug your query.

```
    protected bool checkType(SearchResultItem Ritem)
    {
        if (Ritem.type != null ||  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ritem.type))
        {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the where condition to

```
 public class SearchItem : SearchResultItem
 {
    [IndexField("type")]
    public string Type{ get; set; }    
 }

 public class Search
 {
    public static IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
    {
       List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

       var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(new SitecoreIndexableItem(Sitecore.Context.Item));

       using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
       {
            var indexItems = context.GetQueryable<FRBSearchResultItem>()
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["type"]))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ReleaseDate);

            foreach(var indexItem in indexItems)
            {
                var tempItem = indexItem.GetItem();
                items.Add(tempItem);
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late for the answer but might help future readers with the same problem.

I am using predicate builder as follows,

```
faqPredicate = faqPredicate.And(x => x.FAQAudience != null);
```

This results in below error

Message: Comparison of null values is not supported.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Lucene

So to fix it while indexing instead of return string.Empty i used  return "null";

and in the predicate i checked,

```
faqPredicate = faqPredicate.And(x => x.FAQAudience != "null");
```

Yes, it's a workaround but it works. I also tried a comparison with string.Empty but that didn't worked